# Laravel Like in Query Builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a problem here, I did a search with the query builder, the database status column is varchar, which is active, inactive, disable

the problem here, if I look for an active status then inactive also appears

```
 $vendor  = DB::table('client_vendor as cv')
                        ->leftJoin('vendors as fv','fv.id','=','cv.vendor_id')
                        ->select('cv.*','fv.*','cv.status')
                        ->where('cv.status', 'LIKE', '%' . 'active' . '%')
                        ->get();
```

here I may not change the data type in the database

Comment: you miss semicoloun in last of code.

Comment: @VikasKatariya yes sorry,  just in here, but in my code there is semicoloum

Comment: yes  exectly.. Happy Coding..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

```
 $vendor  = DB::table('client_vendor as cv')
                        ->leftJoin('vendors as fv','fv.id','=','cv.vendor_id')
                        ->where('cv.status','=','active')
                        ->get();
```

**EDIT**

```
$vendor  = DB::table('client_vendor as cv')
                        ->join('vendors as fv','fv.id','=','cv.vendor_id')
                        ->select('cv.*','fv.*')
                        ->where('cv.status','active')  // or  ->where('cv.status','=','active')
                        ->get();
```

Comment: can you get your answer?

Answer (score 2):

That's because `LIKE '%active%'` also fits for `inactive`. Special char `%` can be replaced by any string. In your case you should just use `=`, not `LIKE`. It will also be much faster, especially if you add KEY/INDEX to that column in database.

There you can find `LIKE` operator explanation: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp